# Using jquery Callbacks.fire method as a event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, callback

So I've got a jquery project where I'm using an external class that has callback style events.
Meaning, it has an "onSave" property that takes one function. However, I need to more than one other components to hook into it.

What I've settled on for now, goes like this:

```
var saveCallbacks = $.Callbacks();
saveCallbacks.fire.callbacks = saveCallbacks;
globalDoodad.onSave = saveCallbacks.fire;
```

which allows me to do this in my other components:

```
globalDoodad.onSave.callbacks.add( myMethod );
```

Is there a better way to handle this? It seems to be working ok, just has a bit of a smell to it.

Comment: is it breaking your external class in any way? are there any other developers that need to be aware of the changes to the onSave function? If no, I'm not sure I have a problem with it...

Comment: ya, no breakage or team complications. It just seems like a non-standard solution, so I was wondering if there were a more common best practice.

Comment: It's clever, and if it works who am I to disagree... I'm not sure what kind of answer you'll actually get here. Seems more like a question for codereview.se